# Kafka Sink ValueToKey and create Tombstone messages

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Kafka Connector and I am working on

JDBC Sink Connector
Key: String='a' and Value: Avro ={x:'a',y:'b',z:'c'}

Note: I have set all avro properties as 'optional':true.

Connector Configuration-Edit

```
key.converter:StringConverter
value.converter:AvroConverter
Transforms: renameFields,selectFields,valueToKey,DropValue
renameFields.type: ReplaceField$Value
renameFields.renames: x:PM, y:PN
selectFields.type: ReplaceField$Value
selectFields.whiteList: PM,PN
valueToKey.type: ValueToKey
valueToKey.fields: PM,PN
DropValue.type:Drop$Value
schema.behavior: force_optional
delete.enabled: true
pk.mode: record_key
pk.fields: PM, PN
```

Connector fails with the following error:
Cannot ALTER TABLE to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{STRING}, name='y', isPrimaryKey=false}, as the field is not optional and does not have a default value.......

Edit:Added Avro

```
{
"type":"record",
"name":"contact",
"namespace":"avro.generated",
"fields":[
{
"name":"x",
"type":{
"type":"string",
"optional":true,
"avro.java.String":"String"
}
},
{
"name":"y",
"type":{
"type":"string",
"optional":true,
"avro.java.String":"String"
}
},
{
"name":"z",
"type":{
"type":"string",
"optional":true,
"avro.java.String":"String"
}
}
]
```

Comment: Not sure this is the answer, but `rename` property needs to be prefixed by its Transform `renameFields`... Same goes for all the others that aren't the "type". In other words, you need to be setting properties on those specific names... Regarding the actual Avro error, please show the schema

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your reply. I misspelled the Transformation. Otherwise, I am using the right transformation in my connector. I have also updated the post with Avro schema. I will be glad to get more input on this.

Comment: I wasn't saying anything about spelling, rather that `rename: x:PM, y:PN` must be `renameFields.rename: x:PM, y:PN`, and same goes for all the other prefixes

Comment: Also, unrelated, but Avro namespaces cannot have asterisks

Comment: The above things are as you have mentioned. I am using control center UI for connector which has all fields inbuilt just have to assign values to it. Also I put star stating it could be anything in my case the namespace is my org name which I didn't want to mention.

Comment: I don't use Control Center, so I don't know what options are there. I'm just saying, as written in the question, its not a valid property file, **and** your error wouldn't be possible if the rename transform were working as you've tried to configure. Also, I do not think you can use `valueToKey` with any fields since you're using `key.converter=StringConverter`, so it has no structure for fields, plus JDBC sink cannot have structured keys, last I checked

Comment: " JDBC sink cannot have structured keys" I was not aware of this. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Well, I personally have not tried it at least. The docs do refer to listing multiple fields for a key https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#data-mapping